# What is a safe way to stop a GitLab docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm wondering if `docker stop gitlab` is a safe way to stop a GitLab docker container, after I installed a GitLab CE container following the instruction at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html .

Although that GitLab instruction says nothing about how to stop the
container safely in daily use, it tells us to use `docker stop gitlab` in upgrading GitLab.

I suppose that `docker stop ${container_name}` is a common way to stop a container, but am not sure if the standard timeout of 10 seconds is always enough to stop all the GitLab-related processes in the container. Otherwise the GitLab container cannot be properly restarted by doing `docker start gitlab`.

I should admit that I'm a novice user both of Docker and GitLab, so I'd be very grateful for any information about how to temporarily stop a GitLab docker container and how to restart it in daily use.

ps.
Actually I've tried that `sudo docker stop gitlab`, after I created the GitLab docker container to run it by typing :

```bash
$ sudo docker run --detach \
   --hostname localhost \
   --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
   --name gitlab \
   --restart always \
   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
   gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

and changed the root password in the GitLab container.

Then I've done `sudo docker start gitlab` to find that I can login as root with that changed password and that there's no problem in the GitLab container.

So I'm now wondering whether I'm just lucky or `docker stop gitlab` & `docker start gitlab` is completely a safe way to stop and restart all the GitLab-related processes in a GitLab docker container.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to the docker documentation for that:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/#options

Your process will get a "SIGTERM" and have 10 seconds to shut down. If they take longer, they will be stopped with a "SIGKILL".

If you know that your process needs longer, you could use the "-t" option to increase the time.

Is it safe? Well if your hardware is super slow, a gitlab process might take longer and this could be a problem. If you are worried about it, just increase the killtime to several minutes. If it wont shutdown in this time, something is broken.

EDIT:

I created a gitlab container with your command and stopped it immediately:

```
docker stop gitlab
```

The container was not finished setting up, so it took 10s. If we examine it closer, we can verify this:

```
 docker inspect -f '{{.State.ExitCode}}' gitlab
```

Result:

```
 137
```

This can be interpreted as "128 + 9" or "Sigkill".

If I start the container again, let it set up and stop it afterwards:

Result:

```
 0
```

This was just to clarify, that the gitlab docker file is properly set up and it really waits for 10s.

Answer (score 0):

I would first stop the GitLab service the usual way:

```
docker exec <container> gitlab-ctl stop
```

On my server, this command typically completes in more than 10s.

The container continues running even after the service is stopped, so you would still have to stop the docker itself using `docker stop`, as you are doing today.